# android - Assigning recyclerview adapter from AsyncTask, images are loading but onclick NullPointerException is coming

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Without using AsyncTask my coding is working perfectly ...

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView);


    mAdapter = new CardAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

If I am using AsyncTask in mainActivity at setAdapter(mAdapter), in recyclerview onBindViewHolder onClick function I am getting NullPointeerException.

MainActivity :

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView);


    /*mAdapter = new CardAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);*/

    if(isNetworkConnected()) {
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }

//  AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mAdapter = new CardAdapter(mContext);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items

    }
}
```

In Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    NatureItem nature = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.tv.setText(nature.getName());
    viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
    viewHolder.commentClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Comment.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3655)
        at com.example.demo.CardAdapter$3.onClick(CardAdapter.java:227)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your holder implementation and be sure hat you define commentClick. Looks like you forget to do it. Or share all code list

Comment: The 'context' in  `Intent intent = new Intent(context, Comment.class); `maybe null,please try to check it.

Comment: Your component Name that is Comment.class is null...have you registered that component in the android manifest file..Also check whether context is not null as FireSun mentioned

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions,  As u guys mention 'context is null' ....
Please suggest me how to overcome with this!

Comment: If I am not using AsyncTask My coding is working, might be contect is not null. But If I am using AsyncTask I am getting NullPointerExp (context null).  Please give me some suggestions about this.